# arara + Biber: Find .bib files in different folder

Tags: biber, arara

I try to tell Biber through arara to search for .bib files in a different Folder, but am not able to succed.

This is the code I use

```
% arara: biber { options: "--input_directory=C:/...." }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `--input_directory`? (Or `--input-directory` for Biber 1.9.)

Comment: if you use `\addbibresource{<path to bib>/mybib.bib}` then you can just run `arara: biber` without any options (at least, I was able to when constructing a MWE). btw, welcome to the site!

Comment: @egreg Will `biber` still find the `bcf` in the working directory in that case?

Comment: @cfr I don't know. I've never been bothered by auxiliary files in the working directory.

Comment: @egreg thats what I meant, was just a typo in the question and doesn't work for me, but thanks for the fast answer!

Comment: @cmhughes that's how I do it at the moment, but I would like to change the default rule for biber, so every document searchs in the predefined folders.
I just tried it as code in the document itself to safe some time. Thanks for the welcome and the fast answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what I did, but it is working now. I changed the following line in the biber rule file (biber.yaml):

```
command: <arara> biber @{options} "@{getBasename(file)}"
```

to

```
command: <arara> biber --input-directory=C:\Users\******\Documents\Bibliography @{options} "@{getBasename(file)}"
```